How to define a number variable in terraform for Terragrunt to recognise?
I am trying to add a lifecycle rule to my terragrunt file (existing storage bucket) but it keeps erroring with the following message in GCP cloud build
Unsuitable value for var.delete_after set using the TF_VAR_delete_after
environment variable: a number is required.
My storage main.tf
    for_each = var.delete_after == 0 ? [] : [0]
    content {
      action {
        type = "Delete"
      }
      condition {
        age = var.delete_after
      }
    }
  }

  dynamic "lifecycle_rule" {
    for_each = var.lifecycle_rules
    content {
      action {
        type = "SetStorageClass"
        storage_class = lifecycle_rule.value.storage_class
      }
      condition {
        age = lifecycle_rule.value.age
      }
    }
  }

My variables.tf
  description = "Delete objects after X days"
  type        = number
  default = 90
}

variable "lifecycle_rules" {
  description = "Storage class rules only - Use delete_after for deletion rules"
  type        = list(object({age=number,storage_class=string}))
  default     = []
} 

And my terragrunt input block looks like this
  project_id        = dependency.project.outputs.project_id
  name              = "sqlprod_backups"
  location          = "europe-west2"
  storage_class     = "REGIONAL"
  retention_period  = 2592000
  versioning        = false

     delete_after = [{
      age = 90
    
     }]
   lifecycle_rules = [{
      age           = 8
      storage_class = "NEARLINE"
    }]
  access = {
    "roles/storage.objectCreator" = [
      "serviceAccount:sa name"
    ]
  }
} 

I have tried recreating the delete_after variable so it looks like lifecycle_rules variable below it, i have tried to hardcode the value in the main.tf, not sure what is going wrong with this to be honest.
